# Automator script to convert webp file to JPG not working

Tags: macos, applescript, automator, file-conversion

Hi I'm trying to write a Catalina mac Automator script that will convert .WEBP files into .JPG files.

The shell code in Automator I'm using is

```
for img in "$@"; do
 filename=${img%.*}
 /usr/local/bin/convert "$img" -background white -flatten "$filename.jpg"
done
```

This script above converts to jpg but gives the following error:

> The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error:
>
> “convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/562.
>
> convert: no images defined `/Users/Testuser/My Documents/Apple Directory.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3273.”

Can any expert here tell me what's wrong with the code? I'm just dropping the image files on the app icon. Thanks!

Comment: Does it work if you just run `convert` with one of the input files directly in Terminal?

Comment: Yes it does work.. something to do with file handling?

Comment: It looks like one of the files isn't in a format convert understands.

Comment: It’s a .WEBP file and I have installed webp libraries etc using brew

Comment: Are you sure that this is the file `convert` is trying to read?

Comment: Yep i am sure the file is webp image format

Comment: Did you verify that the value of $img points to a webp file at the moment it gets called? If yes, I would put the whole code in a shell script and call it, using the full path of the files you want to convert.

Comment: Maybe coz the image webp file is in same directory as the script app?

Comment: We can't see what's going on on your system unless you show it to us :-)

Comment: Does that command you're trying to run just get the last frame of the WebM video saved as a JPEG file?